# Как загрузить xib файл в качестве subview в UIView программным способом?

Tags: ios, swift

Я ранее создавал xib файлы и загружал их в UIView, но делал это через storyboard. И это работало. Теперь у меня другая ситуация, мне нужно добавить этот xib программно в заранее подготовленную UIView.

Я пробовал разные примеры, но у меня ничего не выходит. То просто ничего не отображается на экране (т.е. никакого результата), с другими примерами вообще ошибка вылетает.

Вот содержимое xib файла:

```swift
import UIKit

class SmaatoViewAd: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var content_description: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var call_to_action: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var image_content: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let xibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SmaatoViewAd", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! UIView
        xibView.frame = self.bounds
        xibView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(xibView)
    }
}
```

Допустим у меня в моём классе UIViewController есть UIView элемент, мне надо в него загрузить этот xib файл и желательно ещё, чтобы он принял ширину этого UIView и задал ему высоту. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для добавления программно Вам необходимо переопределить init(frame:)

```
override func init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // прописываете все что необходимо
 }
```

И затем добавляете.

Answer (score 0):

переопределите метод loadView у вашего UIViewController. Он как раз и предназначен для "ручного" создания иерархии видов, хотя документация не рекомендует его переопределять в тоже время это делается именно, когда сборка происходит в ручном режиме.

You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the 
view
 property. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

т.е. Вы можете переопределить этот метод чтобы создать ваши виды вручную. Если Вы решите так делать, то назначьте корневой вид вашей иерархии видов в свойство view (основной view вашего контроллера). Виды которые вы создадите нельзя использовать совместно в с любым др контроллером (т.е. эти сабвью могут быть только в иерархии видов вашего контроллера). Ваша кастомизация этого метода НЕ ДОЛЖНА вызывать метод super класса (т.е. super.loadView() не использовать )